# Get interrupt counters like /proc/interrupts from code?

Tags: c++, c, linux, interrupt

I may miss the obvious, but how/is it possible to retrieve interrupt counters for a specific interrupt without manually parsing `/proc/interrupts` from inside a C/C++ program?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards, Martin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/proc/interrupts` and `/proc/stat` obtain their data by calling the kernel function `kstat_irqs_cpu()`. The only way to read it without opening the files in /proc is, I think, writing your own kernel driver which would call the same function and return the results via ioctl() or some other way.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the most stable approach to what I want to achieve. I am fixed on a single architecture, so I _could_ in theory test out the parsing of /proc/interrupts, but this seems more stable to me (but of course more complex :)).

Comment: By looking at the method that shows the interrupts [show_interrupts](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17/source/kernel/irq/proc.c#L514), `arch_show_interrupts` gets called when `i == ACTUAL_NR_IRQS`. This what happens when displaying the contents of `/proc/interrupts`. `kstat_irqs_cpu` does not get called.

Answer (score 6):

On Linux, the text files in `/proc` *are* the canonical user-context interface for most of the information they provide.  For better or worse, parsing that text file is the way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I did some quick checking and it doesn't appear this information is mirrored anywhere under /sys, nor are there any listed syscall numbers which look like it would allow access to this information, so the /proc file is probably the only place it is visible.

You should also be aware that the format is architecture and sometimes kernel configuration specific; the lines are produced by the function show_interrupts, which is usually defined in kernel/irq.c within each architecture subdirectory (eg arch/x86/kernel/irq.c, arch/s390/kernel/irq.c). So you'll probably have to be pretty careful with the parsing (or alternately whitelist the check to only parse the file on architectures you've been able to test it on).